# Unable to install Cisco Anyconnect on windows10

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install cisco AnyConnect 4.3 on Windows 10. I am getting this error:" There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor".

This is a copy of the installation log file:

```
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:28:726]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=VACon64_Install,,)
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:28:726]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=VACon64_Install,ActionType=3090,Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\VACon64.exe,Target=-install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\vpnva64.inf" VPNVA,)
CustomAction VACon64_Install returned actual error code 1018 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:30:848]: Note: 1: 1722 2: VACon64_Install 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\VACon64.exe 4: -install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\vpnva64.inf" VPNVA 
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:56:442]: Product: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action VACon64_Install, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\VACon64.exe, command: -install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\vpnva64.inf" VPNVA 

Action ended 15:49:56: InstallExecute. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:56:454]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:56:455]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (10:A8) [15:49:56:455]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

It seems there is a problem while installing the virtual adapter.

Comment: Are you doing this as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But getting the same problem.

Comment: Why aren't you opening a Cisco TAC case?

Comment: I think the problem is in my adapter driver. The same installer was used on other PC and it worked. In this case would they help? Is it there responsibility?!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem installing 4.5.  You said you tried installing as an administrator.  Is this an account with administrator rights or the Windows 10 Hidden administrator account?  I believe the administrator account is disabled by default in Win10.  When I tried installing from an account with admin rights it gave the same error but after enabling the hidden "administrator" account then installing from that profile I was able to install the new client.

How to enable the hidden "administrator" account:
Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> Administrator -> Properties 
Uncheck " Account is disabled"  You'll also need to set a password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't actually have to set a password, you can set the password to be a blank password, saying you "need to set a password" indicates a blank password won't be accepted.